# jQuery puzzler - can't make slideUp/slideDown work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

With jQuery and CSS I want to show the first of four paragraphs, and add a link/button at the end of that first paragraph. When the link/button is clicked on I want to show the other 3 paragraphs in a slideDown manner and make that link/button go away, and put a link/button at the end that I can use to slideUp the last 3 paragraphs (and have that link/button disappear). Sounds easy, but I can't figure it out. Here's the only html code I have to work with:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
<p>here is first p</p>
<p>here is second p</p>
<p>here is third p</p>
<p>here is forth p</p>
</div>
```

So how can I do this? I've been trying for hours.

Comment: Like this, your question is too broad; add some of the code you have written for solving your task, along with any problems you found. Eventually also setup a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). If you need more information please set up a jsfiddle in order to find what is not working.